# Symfony 3 - PATCH Method doesn't remove/replace elements in a collection

Tags: php, symfony, http-headers

In my entity file `Collection.php` I have self referencing many to many relationship:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Collection")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="collection_related_collections",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="collection_source", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="collection_target", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @JMS\Groups({"collection_related_collections"})
 * @JMS\Expose()
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      max = 3,
 *      maxMessage = "You cannot specify more than {{ limit }} related collections"
 * )
 * @var Collection[]|ArrayCollection $relatedCollections
 */
protected $relatedCollections;
```

This is processed in a controller by a form handler:

```php
$this->get('app_bundle.form.handler.api_form_handler')
     ->process($form);
```

Finnally my `CollectionFormType.php` has `RelatedCollection` field:

```
 ->add('relatedCollections', EntityType::class, [
    'required' => false,
    'choice_value' => 'hashId',
    'choice_label' => function (Collection $collection) {
        return $collection->getName();
    },
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'class' => Collection::class,
    'query_builder' => function (CollectionRepository $collectionRepository) {
        return $collectionRepository->getQueryBuilder();
    }
])
```

Everything works fine when I am trying to `PATCH` an empty `relatedCollection` field:

```
[PATCH] http://symfony.dev/api/collections/{collectionHashId}

{
    "collection": {
        "relatedCollections": ["7D68076025", "196208D03D"]
    }
}
```

But I cannot remove/replace elements trying

```
[PATCH] http://symfony.dev/api/collections/{collectionHashId}

{
    "collection": {
        "relatedCollections": ["7D68076025"]
    }
}
```

This action has no effect. As a result value of `relatedCollection` field remains the same as I set it in the previous request:

```
"relatedCollections": ["7D68076025", "196208D03D"]
```

Also, I cannot remove `relatedCollections` values by sending an empty array `[]`, because it makes no changes at all.

Is there a way to *replace/remove* `ArrayCollection` values using **PATCH Method**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this with `PUT` as well with a similar result? I suspect this is caused by the "owner" of the relationship being the child; in this case `RelatedCollection` as I understand it.

You'll need to update the *owning* side of the relationship if that is the case. Check this out for more information: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html

Comment: There is no separate owning side in this relation. Both 'joinColumns' and 'inverseJoinColumns' are defined in the same entity's property '$relatedCollections'.  PUT method behave strange as well - instead of rewriting existing values it creates a new record. All others entities using this form handling structure work correctly with POST, PUT and PATCH methods.

Comment: I also tried `orphanRemoval` and `cascade` in this relationship but it hasn't changed its behavior.

Comment: Are you using the `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` correctly?

The inverse side has to use the mappedBy attribute of the OneToOne, OneToMany, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The mappedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the owning side.

The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.

Comment: There is no `inversedBy` and `mappedBy` in this relation. In the annotation, I use the same field for inverting and mapping. It can be seen as follow `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Product\Collection", mappedBy="relatedCollections", inversedBy="relatedCollections")`

Comment: I'm guessing that's your problem then :)